# Data structure manipulation with Pandas

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas

I have a list of dicts as follows :

```
[
{
    "status": "BV", 
    "max_total_duration": null, 
    "min_total_duration": null, 
    "75th_percentile": 420, 
    "median": 240.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 180, 
    "avg_total_duration": null
}, 
{
    "status": "CORR", 
    "max_total_duration": null, 
    "min_total_duration": null, 
    "75th_percentile": 1380, 
    "median": 720.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 420, 
    "avg_total_duration": null
}, 
{
    "status": "FILL", 
    "max_total_duration": null, 
    "min_total_duration": null, 
    "75th_percentile": 1500, 
    "median": 840.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 480, 
    "avg_total_duration": null
}, 
{
    "status": "INIT", 
    "max_total_duration": 11280, 
    "min_total_duration": 120, 
    "75th_percentile": 720, 
    "median": 360.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 180, 
    "avg_total_duration": 2061
}, 
]
```

As is evident,max_total_duration,min_total_duration and avg_total_duration is null for all status except when status is "INIT".What I would want is to remove all the entries for null values and for INIT where max_total_duration,min_total_duration and avg_total_duration have correct values, add them as a new dictionary in the list as follows:

```
[
{
    "status": "BV", 
    "75th_percentile": 420, 
    "median": 240.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 180, 
}, 
{
    "status": "CORR", 
    "75th_percentile": 1380, 
    "median": 720.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 420, 
}, 
{
    "status": "FILL", 
    "75th_percentile": 1500, 
    "median": 840.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 480, 
}, 
{
    "status": "INIT", 
    "75th_percentile": 720, 
    "median": 360.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 180, 

}, 
{
    "max_total_duration": 11280, 
    "min_total_duration": 120,
    "avg_total_duration": 2061,
}
]
```

I have tried doing this by iterating over the list and it is computationally very expensive.Is there an easier way of doing this with pandas ?

Comment: why the negative vote ? can i have a justification

Comment: Well..i did try using the conventional method of iterating through the list,find the null values,eliminate them and get the desired result..i have no experience with pandas..if that is what it takes..let me try going through pandas and see if i can solve it myself..

Comment: One thing you could do is 'from numpy import nan as null' then when the data is loaded into a DataFrame some columns have nan values and can be removed with frame.dropna(axis=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# Substituting your 'null' for 'None'
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df
   25th_percentile  75th_percentile  avg_total_duration  max_total_duration  \
0              180              420                 NaN                 NaN
1              420             1380                 NaN                 NaN
2              480             1500                 NaN                 NaN
3              180              720                2061               11280

   median  min_total_duration status
0     240                 NaN     BV
1     720                 NaN   CORR
2     840                 NaN   FILL
3     360                 120   INIT
```

Grabbing the percentiles part:

```
df_percentiles = df[['status','25th_percentile','median','75th_percentile']]

>>> df_percentiles
  status  25th_percentile  median  75th_percentile
0     BV              180     240              420
1   CORR              420     720             1380
2   FILL              480     840             1500
3   INIT              180     360              720
```

Grabbing the durations part:

```
df_durations = df[df['status'] == 'INIT'][['max_total_duration','min_total_duration','avg_total_duration']]

>>> df_durations
   max_total_duration  min_total_duration  avg_total_duration
3               11280                 120                2061
```

Loop and combine to list:

```
summary = df_percentiles.T.to_dict().values()

summary.append(df_durations.T.to_dict().values())

>>> summary
[{'25th_percentile': 180,
  '75th_percentile': 420,
  'median': 240.0,
  'status': 'BV'},
 {'25th_percentile': 420,
  '75th_percentile': 1380,
  'median': 720.0,
  'status': 'CORR'},
 {'25th_percentile': 480,
  '75th_percentile': 1500,
  'median': 840.0,
  'status': 'FILL'},
 {'25th_percentile': 180,
  '75th_percentile': 720,
  'median': 360.0,
  'status': 'INIT'},
 {'avg_total_duration': 2061.0,
  'max_total_duration': 11280.0,
  'min_total_duration': 120.0}]
```

Comment: after the dressing down from Mr.F,I was actually going through the Pandas documentation and trying to solve this..but this is just perfect and exactly what i need..just to understand this better...how does Pandas make it faster than iterating over a loop conventionally and solving this..

Comment: my understanding is that Pandas is based on numpy arrays and hence gets it performance boost my working on the whole list in one shot..if that is the case,does the last two steps of iterating over the lists and combining them not defeat the purpose..Is there not a "pandas" way of combining 2 lists ?

Comment: I've converted the last step to no longer be a loop and instead save directly to a list. AFAIK, you would have to separate the two parts and append as lists since the columns of interest are different and converting to a dictionary would include the `NaN`s otherwise. There may be a way, but I don't know.

On a separate note, I encourage you to continue reading the Pandas docs/tutorials as it is certainly a very useful and versatile library.

Answer (score 2):

```
data =[
{
    "status": "BV", 
    "max_total_duration": None, 
    "min_total_duration": None, 
    "75th_percentile": 420, 
    "median": 240.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 180, 
    "avg_total_duration": None
}, 
{
    "status": "CORR", 
    "max_total_duration": None, 
    "min_total_duration": None, 
    "75th_percentile": 1380, 
    "median": 720.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 420, 
    "avg_total_duration": None
}, 
{
    "status": "FILL", 
    "max_total_duration": None, 
    "min_total_duration": None, 
    "75th_percentile": 1500, 
    "median": 840.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 480, 
    "avg_total_duration": None
}, 
{
    "status": "INIT", 
    "max_total_duration": 11280, 
    "min_total_duration": 120, 
    "75th_percentile": 720, 
    "median": 360.0, 
    "25th_percentile": 180, 
    "avg_total_duration": 2061
}, 
]

data = [{key: val for key, val in d.iteritems() if val} for d in data]

final = []
for d in data:
    status = d.get('status')
    if status == 'INIT':
        final.append({'max_total_duration': d.get('max_total_duration'), 'min_total_duration': d.get('min_total_duration'), 'avg_total_duration': d.get('avg_total_duration')})
        del d['max_total_duration']
        del d['min_total_duration']
        del d['avg_total_duration']
    final.append(d)
print final
```

Comment: @Cody..thanks for that..but i was specifically looking for alternatives using pandas